# updating the linked commit ID in a plugin path used in rake build process

Tags: git, github, rake

In a [build system based on rake](https://github.com/muellermichel/build-couchdb/tree/master/dependencies), someone has linked in specific commits. In the code directory on github this shows up as a directory leading to nowhere, but interestingly, github seems to understand the commit ID, as it is shown after the filename with `@ [commit-id]`, see the screenshot below.

**How can I modify this?** When I clone the repository locally, git just creates empty directories, no meta information to be found. I think I'm missing the right keyword on what that this called. It seems like a URL that can be added as a link to a git project, that github understands.

In the [rake task code in question](https://github.com/muellermichel/build-couchdb/blob/master/tasks/couchdb.rake), these files are called 'plugins', but that doesn't lead me to any useful information either. Rake is able to read the commit ID somehow through an environment variable 'plugins'. I can't figure out how this variable is being set, as the setter doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the repository. Do I need some sort of magic from a rake binary to do what I need?

Any help from someone with more github and/or rake experience would be greatly appreciated.

[image: github display of commit id]

Answer (score 1):

> this shows up as a directory leading to nowhere

It should be a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), if you see a corresponding entry in a .gitmodules.
In which case, a `git clone --recurse-submodules` should be enough.

If not, it is a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)), which only recorded a SHA1, without recording the URL of the distant repo.

The [OP Michel Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501260/michel-m%C3%BCller) confirms it is a submodule, just not referencing the refspec he wants (that is 1.7.0).
All he needs to do (and describes [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197648/6309)) is to go into that submodule, checkout the right tag, go back in the parent folder, add, commit and push.
That would record a new gitlink with the right SHA1.

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be a submodule represented with a 160000 mode entry as well as an entry in .gitmodules. I tried to change it by doing `git rm --cached dependencies/couchdb` and then doing `git submodule add https://github.com/apache/couchdb dependencies/couchdb`, but that didn't seem to work, now I have a strange state in my local repo. doing `git submodule init ; git submodule update` only checks out another dependency, not couchdb, so the dir remains empty. `git ls-tree HEAD dependencies/couchdb` still shows the entry with the old commit. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: @MichelMüller "Seems to be a submodule represented with a 160000 mode entry as well as an entry in .gitmodules" If it was, a simple `git submodule update --init` would have been enough to clone the submodule repo in its subfolder. Try and clone again the repo to see if that is working. Note: with a `git clone --recurse-submodules`, it should already be checked out (and not empty)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, with the help of @VonC I was able to figure this out - thank you! Let me provide a full answer for my question though:

1. This simply were git submodules. The commit that github displays, comes from the git index, i.e. cannot be seen directly in the file system.
2. To change it:

   a. `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/muellermichel/build-couchdb.git`

   b. `cd build-couchdb/dependencies/couchdb`

   c. `git checkout 1.7.0` <-- the tagged version I want to use

   d. `cd ..` <-- very important

   e. `git add couchdb` <-- note: doesn't add the whole couchdb source tree, only the modification of the linked commit.

   f. `git commit && push`

   g. `git ls-tree HEAD dependencies/couchdb/` --> `160000 commit 5f88da2a5ee8ba78917fafd572c7b9fa37e76460  dependencies/couchdb`, shows the new commit.

After pushing, github changes the displayed commit immediately:

[image: new commit]